# What is the reason for the "special" way of blessing in Gemara Moed Katan 9b

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara

In Masechet [Moed Katan 9b](https://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan.9b.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) we find a very special way that looks strange at first sight. The blessing was given for a son that his father sent him to be blessed by Talmidei Hachamim. What was the reason for the special and unclear way that they blessed him. Why did Talmidei Hachamim choose to bless him in this way? Is it acceptable to bless other jews in this way nowadays?

> When Rabbi Yonatan ben Asmai and Rabbi Yehuda, son of converts, noticed Rabbi Shimon ben Yoḥai’s son, they said to him: What do you want here? He said to them: Father told me: Go to them so that they should bless you. They said to him as follows: May it be God’s will that you should sow and not reap, that you should bring in and not take out, that you should take out and not bring in, that your house should be destroyed and your lodging place should be inhabited, that your table should become confused, and that you should not see a new year. When he came back to his father, he said to him: Not only did they not bless me, but they even caused me pain with their negative words.

Comment: The Maharsha explains that they did it to sharpen his mind and that it was never a curse to begin with. Furthermore, he says another reason, that he would have to go back to his father for an explanation, and by explaining it, the bracha would be considered as if it came from R Shimon himself as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is worth noting the commentary of the [Steinsaltz zt'l](https://www.sefaria.org/Steinsaltz_on_Moed_Katan.9b.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)  on this Gemara. He explains that it was  ואמרו בלשון חכמה- the language of the wise men.

> כי אתא לגבי אבוה [כאשר בא אל אביו] אמר ליה [לו]: לא מבעיא דברוכי [די שלברך] לא בירכן [בירכו אותי] אבל צעורי צעורן [אלא אף ציערו אותי] בדברים רעים. אמר ליה [לו] אביו: מאי [מה] אמרו לך? ענה לו: הכי והכי [כך וכך] אמרו לי, אמר ליה [לו] אביו: הנך כולהו ברכתא נינהו [אלה כולן ברכות הן] **ואמרו בלשון חכמה**, וכך פירושן: תזרע ולא תחצד [תקצור] כוונתם: תוליד בנים ולא ימותו. תעייל [תכניס] ולא תיפוק [תוציא] כוונתם: תעייל כלתא [תכניס כלות] לבניך ולא לימותו בנך דליפקון [ימותו בניך שייצאו הכלות בגלל זה ממך]. תיפוק [תוציא] ולא תעייל [תכניס] כוונתם: תוליד בנתא [בנות] ולא ימותו גוברייהו [בעליהן] וליהדרו לותיך [וכתוצאה מכך יחזרו הבנות אליך].

In this vein, Rabbi Tuvia Bolton, from Yeshiva Ohr Tmimim [explains](https://irp-cdn.multiscreensite.com/30ffebf0/files/uploaded/Yeshiva%20Ohr%20Tmimim%20_%20Print%20-%20Torah%20Online%20-%20Festivals%20-%20Lag%20B%27omer%20-%205763.pdf):

> It's not difficult for Tzadikim to give blessings, the difficulty is to be able to accept them.
> in order that Rebbe Shimon's son could receive the blessings (which according to Kabala contained great mystical powers) they all had to first undergo a 'shock' or a 'divorce party' in order to leave their old selves and open their souls to new revelations.

According to Rabbi Tuvia Bolton our eyes need to be opened in order to recognise the blessings and not see them as curses. So, my own interpretation is that Rabbi Shimon ben Yoḥai’s son was not able to recognise that the blessings the Tzadikim gave him, were blessings and not, G-d forbid, curses. Only his eyes needed to be opened in order to perceive them.

Maybe this explanation given by the Lubavitcher Rebbe is also interesting ([Sefer Otsar Hisvaaduios](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/181095/p/157/t/0.47650272765795411234/fs/jr3eC24JDwk810NqxMH5cOeaS9NAItqSByvWv4aNKzzY/start/1864/end/1888/c))

> א מהו הצורך במעלתו של רשב"י דוקא בשביל לפרש דברי התלמידים שכוונתם היא לברכה ולמה לא היה יכול ר' אלעזר בעצמו אפילו אם היה קטן עדיין לפרש את הדברים לטובה
> ב ועיקר הפליאה היא על תלמידי רשב"י למה הוצרכו לברכו בלשון כזה שיכול להביא לפחד ובהלה עד שישמע מאביו את פירוש הדברים והתירוץ לזה כמבואר בלקוטי תורה שהברכה באופן זה היא מבחינת סתום שהיא ברכה נעלית ביותר ולכן יש צורך בזהירות מפני עינא בישא עי"ז שמסתירים אותה בלשון כזה שאינו מובן גם למקבל הברכה עצמו מחשש עינא בישא דמקבל הברכה עצמו
> ורק מצד גודל מעלתו של רשב"י שענינו פנימיות התורה וכמדובר לעיל סעיף ה שענינו לקשר עומק רום עם עומק תחת שגם בעומק תחת מתגלה עומק רום אין מקום וצורך לחשוש ולהזהר מענין בלתירצוי שכן בדרגתו של רשב"י הכל טוב
> בנוגע לנגלה דתורה אמרו חז"ל זכה נעשית לו סם חיים לא זכה וכר היינו שיש גם אפשרות למעמד ומצב דלא זכה שאז הרי זה היפך דסם חיים ח"ו אבל בנוגע לפנימיות התורה אילנא דחיי לא שייך כלל הענין של היפך סם חיים כמבואר בארוכה בקונטרס עץ החיים ולכן בכחו וביכלתו של רשב"י דוקא להמשיך ענין הברכה אפילו בלשון תרגום ובלשון שנראה בגלוי כהיפך הברכה לגלות שזהו ענין של ברכה וברכה נעלית ביותר

Similary, the Lubavitcher Rebbe [here](https://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/tm/3/14/82.htm#_ftnref466). It was the greatness of the Rashbi (Rabbi Shimon bar Yochai) that he was able to interpret the blessings the Tzadikim gave his son. This is also reflected when the [Gemara](https://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan.9b.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says *"These are all blessings, uttered in a cryptic manner, and this is what they meant"*.

Rashbi was able to understand the cryptic blessings his son received from the Tzadikim. The Gemara applies something similair to Daniel, who was able to perceive cryptic visions ([Megillah 3a](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.3a.12?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))